# Purely Functional Controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, functional-programming

Is it possible to use only pure functions to write controllers in AngularJS? I am unable to get my head around where to keep the state and how to manipulate it in a purely functional way.

I am working with the todo application on the Angular home page. The best I could do was separate out the pure parts and call them in the controller methods.

```
var _remaining = R.compose(R.length, R.filter(R.prop('done')));
var _archive = R.filter(R.compose(R.not, R.prop('done')));

class TodoListCtrl {
    constructor() {
        this.todos = [
            {text: 'learn angular', done: true},
            {text: 'build an angular app', done: false}];
        this.todoText = '';
    }
    remaining() {
        return _remaining(this.todos);
    }
    archive() {
        this.todos = _archive(this.todos);
    }
}
```

Note: I am doing a feasibility study to understand if it is possible to use purely functional techniques with AngularJS.

Comment: In angular the state should be kept in the $scope or in an angular service.

Comment: I am using `controllerAs` syntax as suggested [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y031).

Comment: Banging my head on the same question, I've started to read this book: https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide maybe the answer is in there.. I'm still at the beginning..

Comment: 2 years later and we seem to keep on banging our heads on this. One article, also from 2015, that's really good: http://lucasmreis.github.io/blog/a-more-functional-approach-to-angular-with-baobab/
Also another approach using RxJs (which is shipped with angular2): https://fragmentedthought.com/fragments/example-converting-angular-15-use-rxjs

Answer (score 2):

Seems answer is very late. Nevertheless I will still attempt. With Angular 1, controller as a 100% pure function is not possible because `controller` is meant to augment `$scope` (even if you use `controllerAs` syntax) and this `$scope` is the crux of MVVM pattern. And angular view is the side-effect of this `$scope`.

You can abstract as you did up to certain level but that's it. Nothing more than that.